# Locale issue with .NET Core application deployed on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, localization, ubuntu-18.04

I have deployed my .NET Core (v2.1) application onto my Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). The application target audience are UK based.

In C# I am doing:

```
@invoice.Amount.ToString("C")
```

Which formats the value as a currency based on system culture and should show something like `£107.50`, instead I get `$107.50`.

I checked the locale and I had `en_US` so I ran `update-locale LANG=en_GB.utf8` and I restarted everything (kestrel, nginx and session). Now when I run the `locale` command, I get:

```
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

But still, I get `$107.50` instead of `£107.50`. What am I missing?

Comment: `ToString(` method in `C#` should accept second parameter, try `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` or `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)` or `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo('en-GB'))` or `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB'))`. Might require `using System.Globalization`.

Comment: That was it, please reply as Answer so that I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) (with examples in `C#`):

> Standard numeric format strings are supported by some overloads of the
>   `ToString` method of all numeric types. For example, you can supply a
>   numeric format string to the `Int32.ToString(FormatSpecifier)` and
>   `Int32.ToString(FormatSpecifier, IFormatProvider)` methods…

So `.ToString()` method should accept second parameter [*`IFormatProvider`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) (i.e. an object that supplies culture-specific formatting information) in addition to the [*Currency (`"C"`) Format Specifier*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#CFormatString), try

- `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` or
- `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)` or
- `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo('en-GB'))` or
- `@invoice.Amount.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB'))`

(Might require `using System.Globalization`).

I can't provide running `C#` examples at present. However, I can exemplify use of (some) *static* properties and methods of the [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) in PowerShell:

```
PS D:\PShell> 1234.578.ToString('C',[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture)
1 234,58 Kč

PS D:\PShell> 1234.578.ToString('C',[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture)
£1,234.58

PS D:\PShell> 1234.578.ToString('C',[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US'))
$1,234.58

PS D:\PShell> 1234.578.ToString('C',[cultureinfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('de-DE'))
1.234,58 €
```